# IOS Autorotate when I launch from nil file

Tags: ios

I set up my app only support landscape. if the iPad simulator device OrientationLandscapeRight it will fast autorotate from UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft when I launch my app from nib file.But if the iPad simulator OrientationLandscapeLeft or code in application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
there is nothing happen.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)oldStatusBarOrientation{           
   NSLog(@"%d%d%d%d",UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
                    ,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
                    ,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
                    ,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
   NSLog(@"%d",oldStatusBarOrientation);}
```

the logs of launch from nib file:

2013-09-11 11:12:33.235 Wenxianji[925:15203] 1243

2013-09-11 11:12:33.238 Wenxianji[925:15203] 1

2013-09-11 11:12:33.251 Wenxianji[925:15203] 1243

2013-09-11 11:12:33.253 Wenxianji[925:15203] 3

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
      self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
      self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

     _spvc   = [[MySplitViewController alloc] init];
     _master = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
     _detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

     _spvc.delegate = _detail;
     _spvc.viewControllers = @[_master, _detail];

     _master.detailViewController = _detail;

     [self.window setRootViewController:_spvc];
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
      return YES;}
```

the log when program:

2013-09-11 11:26:34.757 Wenxianji[960:15203] 1243

2013-09-11 11:26:34.760 Wenxianji[960:15203] 1

Comment: The simulator rotation on launch doesn't typically happen outside the simulator. Outside the simulator whatever orientation the user already had will be used, unless it's one that you've disabled.

Comment: not the simulator rotate,but the viewController state

Comment: do you want to set a certain orientation for your app or what ? please describe explicitly.

Comment: Yes,I set -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: and -shouldAutorotate return YES,if UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape() equal TRUE.But as described above,when launched from nib lying the iPad simulator device OrientationLandscapeRight the view flashed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

 // enables only landscapeLeft and landscapeRight orientations

 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

1.use this function in every viewController where you need to set its orientation.

2.adjust plist for supported orientation.

3.adjust supported orientation in project->targets->summary->iphone/ipad deployment info.

4.adjust the orientation of view(eg. root view) in property inspector.

inform if issue still persists.

Comment: I have done all you said,but still having problem at first launch,then it will be alright